# Google Analytics - Wrong count is reported for "users" in specifc Segment compared to actual "Users" count

Tags: google-analytics

When I look at the data in Audience Overview and select one of the country segments I’ve set up, for certain time periods I get completely different numbers than those when I’m looking at the segment “All Users” in Geo/Locations.

In below image, "users" from United Stats are reported as 1,773 for period of 2nd May, 2018 to 30th Apr, 2019 (previous period comparison).

[image]

But if run country specific report for 2nd May, 2018 to 30th Apr, 2019 - count of users from United Stats are 6,331.

[image]

It would be great if you can give any insight into why GA providing diffrence counts.

Thanks,
Chintak.

Answer (score 1):

If a segment contains visitor data, date range is automatically limited to 93 days from your start date. However, your time interval is much higher so **the problem** I would say **is in the configuration of your segment**.

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michele, Is this documented somewhere that segment can have only 93 days of data?

Comment: Hi Chintak, it is the interface itself that communicates it, I have updated my answer, look at the screenshot.

Comment: It is documented here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951